# Press Escape key to call method

Tags: c#, methods, key

Is there a way to start a method in C# if a key is pressed? For example, <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

Comment: using what? Console? Form? ASP.NET?

Comment: Note that if your form has a [`CancelButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) configured, then pressing **ESC** will automatically click this button. Depending on your requirements, this may be a good approach.

Comment: C# is a programming language. It has nothing to do with keys being pressed. 
user `Gregoire` asked a long time ago: "using what? Console? Form? ASP.NET?" (And I would add: WPF?) So, even 12 years later, the author of the question still has one thing to do: Answer. Gregoire's. Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am writing WinForms application. User fills the textbox and if he wants to delete everything, he just clicks <kbd>esc</kbd> key on keyboard

I think you need to handle [the KeyDown event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx).

Comment: You will also want to set the form property `KeyPreview` to **True** in order to capture KeyPress events

Answer (score 24):

use the OnKeyPress Event of your textbox and in the event

```
if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Escape)
{
    yourTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: funny, this doesn't seem to be working at all, and it's got five up votes? `private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {...`
This works. But e.KeyChar is a character type, Keys.Escape isn't and the == operator can't be applied.

Comment: Or it could be `e.KeyCode==(char)Keys.Escape`.

Answer (score 18):

As others have mentioned, handle the `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` event of the appropriate control. The `KeyPress` event would work for the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key as well, though it will not trigger for some keys, such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>ALt</kbd>.

If you want to execute this function anytime the user presses the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key, then you probably want to handle the event on the Form.  If you do this, you will probably also want to set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to true.  This will allow the Form control to receive the event even if the focus is currently inside of one of the child controls.

If you want the behavior to be specific to a control, such as clearing the text within a textbox that currently has focus, then you should handle the `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` event of the `TextBox` control. This way, your event handler will not be triggered if the user presses the escape key outside of the textbox.

In some situations you might want to prevent child controls from handling the same event that you've just handled.  You can use the `SuppressKeyPress` property on the `KeyEventArgs` class to control this behavior:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Escape key pressed");

        // prevent child controls from handling this event as well
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In case someone is looking for how to do this in a **console application**

```
if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to switch the **form property "KeyPreview" to true** or your events will not be fired. Handling these events alone will not do anything even though the events are correct. It will look to you like nothing really happens even though you have subscribed the proper event handlers.

Answer (score 3):

First in Properties do > KeyPreview : True

Then :

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            //call your method here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing a Console application, a WinForms application or something else? Are you trying to capture the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key at all times (regardless of the focused window/application) or something else?

More context required.

If you're writing a Console app, then you should start looking at things like Console.ReadKey...

<sup>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx</sup>

Comment: I am writing WinForms application. User fills the text box and If he wants to delete everything, he just clicks esc key on keyboard

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is listed here several time

Implement Form_KeyDown

```
Private Sub frmCustomerSearch_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Try
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then

                ClearFindForm()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

End Sub
```

Set form.keyPreview

```
form.KeyPreview = true
```

The additional thing you need to check is whether you have a button capturing ESC so it can be the form.cancelButton

to be sure ...

```
form.CancelButton = nothing
```

This is sneaky. If you have set that and forgot about it, the Escape key will not trigger the KeyDown event.

I was led to this because a button set to be the form.CancelButton does not seem to fire if it is invisible or on a non visible tab,so KEYDOWN is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

With Event KeyPress...

```
   //Escape 
   if (e.KeyChar == '')
   {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            e.Handled = true;
   }
```

Comment: `(char)Keys.Escape` is same as `'\x1B'` is same as `(char)27` but **is not same as** `''`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. But you can still use the event just change the condition of e.keychar

Answer (score 1):

You can use KeyUp event too. I prefer it though.

```
private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) {
     if (e.Key == Key.Escape) {
         //WHAT WILL HAPPEN INSERT HERE
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with ASP.NET e. g. [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor)'s [`@keydown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling) event you don't have access to the `Key` enum in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. Instead you have to check for the literal string:

```
<div @onkeydown=@HandleKeyDown></div>
```

---

```
private async void HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == "Escape")
   {
      // implementation
   }
}
```