# Capture ESC in textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to have the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key undo any changes to a textbox since it got focus.

I have the text, but can't seem to figure out how to capture the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Both `KeyUp` and `KeyPressed` don't seem to get it.

Comment: Please post your code and tell us if this is winforms, webform, WPF or something else.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798383/press-escape-key-to-call-method for a similar answer. Effectively handle the OnKeyPress event and then check for e.KeyCode (as per keyboardP's answer). Please post your current attempt!

Comment: It won't work when the textbox is shown in a dialog, Escape is a shortcut key designed to cancel the dialog.  You can derive your own class from TextBox and override IsInputKey().  You shouldn't.

Answer (score 10):

This should work. How are you handling the event?

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{          
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Escape Pressed");
    }
 }
```

Edit in reply to comment - Try overriding `ProcessCmdKey` instead:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
     if (keyData == Keys.Escape && myTextBox.Focused) 
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Escape Pressed");
     }

     return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. When the ESC key is pressed, it never enters this function (it does for "normal" keys)

Comment: Does overriding the `ProcessCmdKey` work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx Before you use `ProcessCmdKey`, try the first method and ensure KeyPreview is set to `true`. For example, in your form constructor, add `this.KeyPreview = true;
`

Comment: This will affect the form. I only want to capture for this one textbox.

Comment: Check if your textbox has focus `if(keyData == Keys.Escape && myTextBox.Focused)`

Comment: check that you don't have the cancel/accept button code still in effect in your form.

Comment: in my case, only KeyDown can capture escape key press. KeyUp cannot capture it.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you're looking for?

```
    string origStr = String.Empty;
    private void txtOrig_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        origStr = txtOrig.Text;
    }

    private void txtOrig_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Escape))
        {
            txtOrig.Text = origStr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No. As has I have explained, the ESC key never fires the `KeyPress` event

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly some keys are not considered "input keys" and so are not listened to by default. You need to handle `PreviewKeyDown` first to enable it.

```
myTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => {
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) {
      e.IsInputKey = true;
      Debug.Print("ESC should get handled now.");
   }
};
```

However, results from testing say otherwise, so it may depend on framework version. For me, whether I do that or not, `KeyDown` does not get called for ESC, and whether I do that or not, `KeyPress` DOES get called for ESC. This is while a TextBox has focus, so it may also depend on the control.