# Novice MVVM in C# trying to close application with Esc (handling key commands)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, keydown

I'm learning/practicing basic MVVM framework solutions in C#

I have a small program that plays around with a ComboBox, if user select something from box, it is displayed in a MsgBox. Now I want it to close on esc key. I found a lot of solved questions here about that like these:

[Keyboard events in a WPF MVVM application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612966/keyboard-events-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application)
[Press Escape key to call method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798383/press-escape-key-to-call-method)

But I'm unable to implement any of these... I dont even seems to be able to set KeyPreview to True (Im okey to just write in to the Form now, but the funny thing is, I can't make it work.)

My problems are, I did not use c# for a while, Im not sure what to use exactly (KeyEventArg KeyEventHandler, should I use e.Key, e.keyDown?) and Im not sure where to put this code. I read a few things about how to handel it in the XAML file, which would be the best but was unable to do it. Right now here is my code in the App.xaml.cs, I tried to implement it in various places but I reather ask when Im coding and dont know what to do/what Mi doing exactly, so here Im.

My code right now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfComboBoxStrinbgListMVVM
{



    public class MainViewModel
    {

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ItemList = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
        }
        public List<string> ItemList { get; set; }

        private string seletedElement;
        public string SelectedElement
        {
            get { return seletedElement; }
            set
            {
                seletedElement = value;
                MessageBox.Show(seletedElement);
            }
        }

        private void EscKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Escape key pressed");
                // mainWindow.Close();? MainWievModel.Close(); App.Close();

            }

        }

        //private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        //    {
        //        MessageBox.Show("Escape key pressed");

        //        // prevent child controls from handling this event as well
        //        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        //    }
        //}

    }

}
```

Comment: I m unable to make the Esc key pressed MsgBox appear, pls ask anything that you need if you want to help me :)

Comment: "Now I want it to close on esc key" - What is "it" ?

Comment: The application it self, the program, the entire thing (I have another project where on Esc the login window vanishes but still runs in the task manager, I would like to be able to close it properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest method in this case would be to use the predefined [ApplicationCommands.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.close(v=vs.110).aspx) command

this would look like this

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

then in the codebehind

```
this.CommandBindings.Add(
  new CommandBinding(
    ApplicationCommands.Close,
    (s,a)=>Application.Current.Shutdown() //or this.Close() depending on what you want to close
  )
);
```

other options would include implementing a custom class that uses the ICommand interface  or using one of the hundreds of libraries that provide this functionality such as [prism's Delegate Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410(v=pandp.50).aspx) or the [Relay command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

EDIT

as you are not familiar with anonymous delegates the code behind could also be written like this

```
this.CommandBindings.Add(
  new CommandBinding(
    ApplicationCommands.Close,
    PerformClose
  )
);

public void PerformClose(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I tried a lot off different approaches like this, tried Application.Close and App.Close and this.Close and etc... Can you explain it to me what does this line do? : (s,a)=>Application.Current.Shutdown() and why do we need it after ApplicationCommands.Close? and what are (s,a) ?

Comment: `(s,a)=>` defines an anonymous delegate that accepts 2 arguments in this case  object s and eventAgs e, the standard event handler finger print, `Application.Current` gets the currently running application and the shuddown method is the command to close the selected application

Comment: I'm sorry if I bother you but how does the program knows that s is an object type ? a is eventArgs? and where are they specified? to me it looks like somekind of black magick that (s,a) => part (and but I want to understand not just implement)

Comment: its because the definition for the `CommandBinding` constructor specifies that the delegate is of type `ExecutedRoutedEventHandler` which then defines the types of the arguments

Comment: I see, here is the doc if anyone is interested:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use KeyBinding,sample code like below:

```
<InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
</InputBindings>
```

In window.xaml(I'm afraid you have to write a little code behind :(  )

```
Window(){
  InitializeComponent();
  this.DataContextChanged += (sender,e){
    var vm = e.NewValue as WindowViewModel;
    if(vm != null){
       vm.CloseFunc = () => this.Close();
    }
 }
```

}

For WindowViewModel:
    public Action CloseFunc{get;set;}

```
private RelayCommand _closeCommand;
public RelayCommand CloseCommand =>
     _closeCommand??(_closeCommand = 
    new RelayCommand(() =>{
       CloseFunc?.Close();
   })));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but cant I just use the Binding CloseCommand like anyother MVVM "commands" like this:    [code]                                   
 private string seletedElement;
        public string SelectedElement
        {
            get { return seletedElement; }
            set
            {
                seletedElement = value;
                MessageBox.Show(seletedElement);
            }
        } [code]

Comment: @BasicHumanBeing Command Binding is how you would handle any other Commands, however the method of handling that binding can be done in different ways

Comment: @Jake , I got errors in both the windiw.xaml and in the WindowViewModel. In WVM: action and relaycommands namespace could not be found and in window.xaml.cs (I assume thats where you instructed me to write it) after sender e) the IDE excpect a "=>" and it doesnt recognize the CloseFunc (also I never saw this before, what does it do:  = () =>  isnt a simply this.close should do it?)

Comment: @BasicHumanBeing relay command isn't part of the .net framework you need to either write it yourself or grab a library that has done that for you  i think jake is using http://www.mvvmlight.net/